# Disabling sound in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS updated

Tags: nvidia, sound

Something has gone completely wrong with the sound in my PC.  The volume control is stuck on mute, and even when the mute box is cleared and a volume is set, the volume resets to mute immediately.  The set volume box in the upper right corner continually flashes when a browser is open, and it completely clogs up the computer while it hunts.  I have to leave the browser and come back to work, and it even affects typing.

I have sound though my NVidia 610GT video card as well as embedded in the ASUS M5PG41 M LE motherboard.  It doesn't matter which source I choose in sound settings, the volume control bar flashes on and off and clogs the computer.

Sound is also stuck in mute in Windows XP, but clogging isn't as bad.

I can live without computer sound;  given the death of my UPS battery recently, the several times electric power has gone on and off or flickered when the computer was receiving power, and the age of my PC, it's probably time for a replacement computer.

Is it possible this is a motherboard software, not hardware problem?

Would a separate soundcard make a difference?

Can sound be completely disabled in Ubuntu?  This would be my preferred solution.

Is there such a thing as a repair install in Ubuntu?

Should I try and reinstall the audio drivers from the motherboard CD and from the video card CD?  The NVidia driver is proprietary and is installed.

Are there other possible solutions?